# How to stop a player collecting the same passenger...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a game for class and the objective of the game is to move a player around the grid and collect all the passengers and deliver them to the base.

Thanks to the help of others I have managed to do everything that is needed however I ran into one issue that is when the user collects a passenger and delivers them to the base, they could keep collecting the same passenger when they are meant to collect all four separately. My map is constructed with the following array:

```
var map = [
        [
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: "P"
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            }],
           [ {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            }

        ],
    [ {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: "P"
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            }

        ],

        //SEPERATION

        [ {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: "B"
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            }

        ],

        // SEPERATION

    [ {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            }

        ],

        // SEPERATION

        [ {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            }

        ],

        // SEPERATION

        [ {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: "P"
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: "P"
            }

        ],

        // SEPERATION

        [ {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            }

        ],

        // SEPERATION

        [ {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            }

        ],

        // SEPERATION

        [ {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
            {
                color: "g",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "w",
                letter: ""
            },
             {
                color: "b",
                letter: ""
            }

        ]

];
```

I then check the colours and whether it is a passenger with these functions:

```
function checkCol(cell, row){
        var color = map[row][cell].color;
    console.log(color);
    if (color == "g") {
       playerPower -= deductG;
    } else if (color == "b") {
       playerPower -= deductB;
    } else if (color == "w") {
     playerPower -= deductI;
    }


        switch (color){
            // Brown
            case "b":
                break;
            // Green
            case "g":
                break;
            // White   
            case "w":
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
function checkPass(cell, row) {
    var pass = map[row][cell].letter;
    console.log(pass);
    if (pass == "P" && passengerCarrying != passengerSize && passOnLevel != 0) {
        alert("Passenger Collected!");
        passengerCarrying += 1;
//alert(passengerCarrying);
//alert(passengerSize);
        // Remove the passenger collected here
    } else if (pass == "P" && passengerCarrying == 0) {
        alert("Your passenger bay is full!");
    }
} 

function checkBase(cell, row) {
    var base = map[row][cell].letter;
    console.log(base);
    if (base == "B" && passengerCarrying != 0 && passOnLevel != 0) {
        passOnLevel -= passengerCarrying;
        passengerCarrying = 0;
        alert("Passengers Delivered!");
if (passOnLevel == 0 && passengerCarrying == 0 && playerPower >= 0) {
    alert("You Win!");
    window.location.href='customise.php';
}

    } else if (base == "B" && passengerCarrying == 0 && passOnLevel != 0) {
        alert("You must collect some passengers!");
    } //else if (base == "B" && passengerCarrying == 0 && passOnLevel == 0) {
       // alert("You Win!");
        //window.location.href='customise.php';
   // }
}
```

I check these when the player moves like this:

```
checkPass(playerPos[0], playerPos[1]);
                checkBase(playerPos[0], playerPos[1]);
                checkCol(playerPos[0], playerPos[1]);
```

My issue as mentioned previously is how can I stop a player from picking up the same passenger over and over?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: 1.) Giant walls of code don't usually get answers
2.) It's really helpful to have a working sample.

Comment: I would but there is PHP which won't allow me to work correctly because to make the game work it requires $_SESSION variables :(

Comment: Why aren't you just marking a passenger as no longer available once they're picked up?  Or, checking to see if the passenger is already in the car and thus can't be picked up again or checking to see that this player has already transported this passenger and thus can't transport them again?  There are lots of possible solutions here depending upon the details of your game/assignment which you haven't fully described.

Comment: That's it though. I want to mark them as picked up but I'm not sure how to. :/ If you want all my code I can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this in your `checkPass` function:

```
map[row][cell].letter = "";
```

This will get the letter of whatever box the player is currently on and set it to empty, therefore it is no longer seen as a passenger. Your function will now look like this:

```
    function checkPass(cell, row) {
        var pass = map[row][cell].letter;
        console.log(pass);
        if (pass == "P" && passengerCarrying != passengerSize && passOnLevel != 0) {
            alert("Passenger Collected!");
            passengerCarrying += 1;
      map[row][cell].letter = "";
    //alert(passengerCarrying);
    //alert(passengerSize);
            // Remove the passenger collected here
        } else if (pass == "P" && passengerCarrying == 0) {
            alert("Your passenger bay is full!");
        }



}
```